# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances - objects

Tags: python

I am trying to sort by name but it is typing an Error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Person' and 'Person'. Could you tell me where the problem is? Here is my code.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, year_of_birth, degree):
        self.name = name
        self.year_of_birth = year_of_birth
        self.degree = degree
        self.mentor = None
        self.mentees = []

def create_mentorship(mentor, mentee):
    mentee.mentor = mentor
    mentor.mentees.append(mentee)

def get_founder(people):
    for person in people:
        if people[person].mentor == None:
            return people[person]

def print_mentorship_tree(people):
    person = get_founder(people)
    print_mentorship_subtree(person)


def print_mentorship_subtree(person, level=0):
    a = []
    print((" " * level) + person.name +' (' + str(person.year_of_birth) + ')')
    for mentee in person.mentees:
        print_mentorship_subtree(mentee, level + 1)
        a = sorted(person.mentees)

    >>> people = {}
    >>> people['Martin'] = Person('Martin', 1991, 'phd')
    >>> people['Lukas'] = Person('Lukas', 1991, 'phd')
    >>> people['Tom'] = Person('Tom', 1993, 'mgr')
    >>> people['Honza'] = Person('Honza', 1995, 'bc')
    >>> create_mentorship(people['Martin'], people['Tom'])
    >>> create_mentorship(people['Tom'], people['Honza'])
    >>> create_mentorship(people['Martin'], people['Lukas'])
    >>> print_mentorship_tree(people)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so.py", line 38, in <module>
    print_mentorship_tree(people)
  File "so.py", line 20, in print_mentorship_tree
    print_mentorship_subtree(person)
  File "so.py", line 28, in print_mentorship_subtree
    a = sorted(person.mentees)
TypeError: unorderable types: Person() < Person()
```

Comment: This compare operator must be defined as method in the class because Python doesn't know how to compare `Person`s. In this case method name is `__lt__`.

Answer (score 4):

It's just what it says: you cannot sort `Person` objects.  If you want this to work, you have to define at least the `__lt__` operator for your class, using whatever sort criterion you had in mind -- perhaps alphabetical by name?

Another possibility is to simply write your own function, and call it with `person.mentees.obj_sort`.

---

Also, I'm not sure why this matters: you never *use* the return value of this operation.  You store it in the local variable `a` (that's a poor variable name, by the way), and never use it.

Answer (score 4):

How about writing a custom [key](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) function and pass it as `sorted()` argument?

`sorted_list = sorted(person.mentees, key=lambda p: p.name)`